# Getting Display Name via Steam ID for Non-Friends

Tags: c++, steam

When using the Steamworks SDK (in C++), is there any way to get the display/persona name from the `CSteamID` object, even if we are not friends on Steam? Or is this possible for friends only?

In that case, when using a Steam leaderboard, how else should I display the nick names of the leaderboard entries in my game?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov As it turned out I already get all display names, no need to explicitly request for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
SteamFriends.GetFriendPersonaName(steamUserID);
```

To get the user name even if they are not in your friends list. I have tested this out using Steamworks.NET in Unity.

Comment: I did that and get Unknown

Comment: I did that too, and got "[unknown]" string as a result, too. Did that for a friend just to verify if the function works at all, and it did return the correct name for the friend.